# Can't use "super" to refer to a name that was brought in by "use" from another crate

Tags: module, namespaces, rust, super

I am using `super` inside a module to refer to names in the parent namespace.  However, I cannot get this to work when I refer to a name in the parent namespace that was brought in with a `use` statement.  What am I doing wrong?

```
// crate mylib

pub fn lib_hello() {println!("Hello from mylib!");}


// crate mybin

extern crate mylib;
use mylib::lib_hello;

fn local_hello() {println!("Hello from here!");}

mod mymod {
    fn f() { super::local_hello() } // Ok
    fn g() { super::lib_hello() }   // error: unresolved name `super::lib_hello`
}

fn main() {
    lib_hello(); // Ok
}
```

**edit: remove `pub` from local_hello**

**Further clarification on what I am asking**:  The function `local_hello()` is declared as private in the crate namespace.  The function `lib_hello()` is brought in with `use` and also becomes a private name in the crate namespace.  At this point the names `local_hello` and `lib_hello` have equal stature: they are both in the crate namespace, and both are private.  In `mymod` I use `super` to refer to the crate namespace and can get access to `local_hello` but not `lib_hello`.  What gives?

I know about Python and C++ namespaces.  Perhaps there is some crucial bit I need to unlearn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`use` statements only import to the local scope. If you want to reexport, use `pub use`

```
// crate mylib

pub fn lib_hello() {println!("Hello from mylib!");}


// crate mybin

extern crate mylib;
pub use mylib::lib_hello;

pub fn local_hello() {println!("Hello from here!");}

mod mymod {
    fn f() { super::local_hello() } // Ok
    fn g() { super::lib_hello() }   // error: unresolved name `super::lib_hello`
}

fn main() {
    lib_hello(); // Ok
}
```

`pub use` will make the item seem like it exists in the module being reexported from.

Comment: Apologies, I did not mean `local_hello()` to be marked as `pub` and I do not mean it to be exported outside this crate (pretend this is a lib crate for a moment).  Similarly, I want to use `lib_hello()` but do not want to re-export it from this crate, which is what I think `pub use` does.  Does this change the answer?

Comment: Relevant Rust book link: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/crates-and-modules.html#re-exporting-with-pub-use

Comment: @goertzenator, yes, it does change the answer in the sense that it is not possible to `use` something which is not exported from parent or sibling module and which is not defined in the parent or sibling module itself.

Comment: Thanks, but I feel... unsatisfied.  The docs lead me to believe that a name can only be public or private, but from what I'm seeing here there is really a third mode which is "private-with-extra-restrictions".  Is there good reason for Rust to work like this or is this a use-case that was maybe overlooked/postponed?

Comment: @goertzenator You're mistaking the meaning of "private" here, names are _local to the module_, which doesn't include child modules. There are only two modes. I don't see any reason to have this feature; `use` is pretty lightweight. Since modules are generally split into files, `use` is important to be able to trace back an identifier without needing to step out of the file.